# The [...], together with [...], make[s]

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

In the following sentence construct:

> [...], together with [...], make [...]

Would "make" be considered singular (and thus take an `s`), or plural?

Comment: I would read the central phrase as parenthetical, therefore secondary. If the opening subject is singular, it **makes** sense to use a singular verb to match it.

Comment: See also the [linked questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/56210?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

This would depend on whether the first "[...]" is singular or plural.

> [...], together with [...], make [...]

- If it is singular, then the verb will be *makes*
- If it is plural, then the verb will be *make*

I base my response on the following clarifications:

- Punctuations in the question specify that focus is more on the first "[...]". The first "[...]" is the subject as far as the sentence is concerned.
- Without the punctuations, it can be argued that either the first or the second "[...]" can be a subject depending on the context.

Comment: Please do not use "the below"; use "the following" or "this" instead. Please do not use backticks to format code on ELU because we don't have code here.